# Incorrect syntax in SQL statement comparing a datetime

Tags: sql, syntax-error

I want to filter in a datetime datatype column (column `DATE_AND_TIME`) to detect of the time is in the rush hour and not on a weekend day. In my SQL statement below I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near '>'.

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT 
    CASE
       WHEN DATEPART(HH, DATE_AND_TIME) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 
            AND DATE_AND_TIME != DATEPART(DW, DATE_AND_TIME + @@DATEFIRST - 1) > 5 
          THEN 'RUSH HOUR'
       WHEN DATEPART(HH, DATE_AND_TIME) BETWEEN 16 AND 19 
            AND DATE_AND_TIME != DATEPART(DW, DATE_AND_TIME + @@DATEFIRST - 1) > 5 
          THEN 'RUSH HOUR'
       ELSE 'NOT RUSHHOUR'
    END
FROM 
    TRAFFIC
```

Comment: Your code is a mess.  Try to spell out your logic and match it to the code.

Comment: your error is here:
`DATEPART(DW, DATE_AND_TIME + @@DATEFIRST - 1)` you can't have two comparisons at once. either, leave `> 5` or `!=DATE_AND_TIME`

Comment: What's `@@DATEFIRST`?

Comment: @@DATEFIRST specifies the first day of the week.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: why to mess with this ??you can use datetime between x and y instead!!!
where x,y=your rushhour details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (DATEPART(HH,DATE_AND_TIME) BETWEEN 7 AND 9) AND DATE_AND_TIME != DATEPART(DW, DATEADD(DAY,@@DATEFIRST - 1,DATE_AND_TIME))  AND DATEPART(DW, DATEADD(DAY,@@DATEFIRST - 1,DATE_AND_TIME)) > 5 AND  THEN 'RUSH HOUR'
            WHEN (DATEPART(HH,DATE_AND_TIME) BETWEEN 16 AND 19) AND DATE_AND_TIME != DATEPART(DW, DATEADD(DAY,@@DATEFIRST - 1,DATE_AND_TIME)) AND DATEPART(DW, DATEADD(DAY,@@DATEFIRST - 1,DATE_AND_TIME)) > 5 THEN 'RUSH HOUR'
            ELSE 'NOT RUSHHOUR' END
FROM TRAFFIC
```